# Linking Three tables and finding data that matches requirements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three PostgreSQL tables: Addresses, Shipments, and Schedules.
Shipments and Schedules both have foreign keys for the address.

The address table has information about an address: id, name, number, street, state, zip
The shipment table has: id, tracking number, date_ship_on, address_id
The schedule table has: id, sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thrusday, friday, saturday, type, address_id

All the days in the schedule table are boolean values ex: id=2, sunday=false, monday=true, tuesday=true, wednesday=true, thrusday=false, friday=false, saturday=false, type='reporting', address_id=1

What I'm trying to do is, link the three tables together and find the address that didn't have a shipment sent out yesterday and it was supposed to based on the schedule with type 'reporting'. So for example, we have 3 addresses, Chicago, LA, NYC, today is Tuesday, Chicago sent out two shipments yesterday (date shipped on is stored in date_shipped_on, so it would have yesterdays date and we can find what day yesterday was from this date) but LA and NYC didn't send anything out, Chicago and LA both had true for Monday on their reporting schedules but NYC didn't. What I should get back is LA from my results since it didn't have a shipment sent out Monday but was supposed to based on the schedule. I'll be running this report every day for the previous day.

I've tried a few different things but to no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM address a INNER JOIN schedule s ON a.id = s.address_id

-- no shipment sent out yesterday
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM shipment sh 
    WHERE sh.address_id = a.id
    AND date_ship_on >= TIMESTAMP 'yesterday'
    AND date_ship_on < TIMESTAMP 'today')

-- was supposed to based on the schedule with the type 'reporting'
AND s.type = 'reporting'
AND (
       (s.sunday = true     AND extract(dow from current_timestamp) = 1)
    OR (s.monday = true     AND extract(dow from current_timestamp) = 2)
    OR (s.tuesday = true    AND extract(dow from current_timestamp) = 3)
    OR (s.wednesday = true  AND extract(dow from current_timestamp) = 4)
    OR (s.thursday = true   AND extract(dow from current_timestamp) = 5)
    OR (s.friday = true     AND extract(dow from current_timestamp) = 6)
    OR (s.saturday = true   AND extract(dow from current_timestamp) = 0)
);
```

Some explanations:

- TIMESTAMP 'yesterday' is yesterday at midnight
- dow = 0 for sunday, 1 for monday, ...
- We look at sunday schedule if the day of the week of the current time is monday

You may consider another structure for your schedule table if you want to simplify this query. For example : id, day_of_week (int), type, address_id.

**EDIT** : Added inclusive lower bound on timestamp based on Clockwork-Muse's comment.

Comment: Lower bound on timestamps should be inclusive (because midnight may be valid), but upper bounds exclusive (everything before "today").  Point of style: it's usually better to reserve the `WHERE` clause for only conditions that compare against the `FROM` clause reference, and put all other conditions referencing other joins as part of their `ON` clause; this keeps conditions local to the thing they operate on.